# loop over subfolder inside a folder in python

Tags: python, directory-structure

I am trying to move files from one folder to another. I have a folder name from a to z. Inside  each folder(a-z) i have several folders. I can move files from the subfolder of the folder(a-z) to my folder but I want to do it from a-z at once.

```
folder structure : a--ab
                    --ac
                   b--bc
                    --bd
                   .. till z
```

```
import glob
import os
import shutil

path = "E:\\download\\images\\a\\*"
move_path = "E:\\download\\images\\final\\"
files = glob.glob(path,recursive = True)
for file in files:
    subfile= os.listdir(file)
    for sub in subfile:
        subpath = file + "\\" + sub
        shutil.move(subpath,move_path +"\\" + sub)
```

Comment: `images\\*\\*`?

Comment: `images\\*\\*`? like Barmar said or even `for i in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`?

Comment: @Barmar, the `images` folder also contains the `final` folder where the images should be moved.

Comment: Why not just shutil.move the whole directory?

Comment: I used @barmar code and it worked.  images\\*\\*

Answer (score 0):

Copy this tiny script in `E:\download\images` and run it from there. This way, the Path class will use that directory as the working root directory.

The `images` variable will contain a generator that will give you every file matching the glob (which means: every file in every subfolder that has a 3-letter extension and with the first subfolder's name having only one character).

When renaming, the file will be moved from the subfolder path to `final/`, thus being moved.

Keep in mind that the glob will pick every file or folder name having a 3-letter extension. You'll need to do additional checks if you have other files or folders that match this nomenclature.

```
from pathlib import Path

images = Path().glob('?/**/*.???')

for img in images:
    img.rename('final/' + img.name)
```